# What can I use instead of volume for heroku

Tags: docker, heroku, docker-compose, dockerfile

Heroku documentation says that volumes are not supported by heroku: [image]

What should I use instead of volume for heroku?

I have following docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
    
    db: 
        image: mysql:5.7
        volumes:
            - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
            MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
            MYSQL_USER: wordpress
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
        networks:
            - wpsite
            
    wordpress:
        depends_on:
            - db
        image: wordpress:latest
        ports:
            - '8000:80'
        volumes: ['./:/var/www/html']
        environment: 
            WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
            WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
            WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
        networks:
            - wpsite

networks:
    wpsite:
volumes:
    db_data:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding between `dockerfile` and `docker-compose`.

- A [dockerfile](https://docker.github.io/get-involved/docs/communityleaders/eventhandbooks/docker101/dockerfile/#what-is-a-dockerfile) allows to build docker images
- A [compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) file allows to define and run multi-container Docker applications
- You can use `volumes` in `docker-compose.yml` as shown in that documentation from Heroku :
  [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-development-with-docker-compose#introduction-to-docker-compose)
- You can not use `VOLUME` instruction in a `dockerfile` which is described in the following documentation:
  [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume)